# DIfferent loss functions for first value of output

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I have CNN with ouput

```
[[a,b,c,d,e],[a1,b1,c1,d1,e1]...]
```

However the "a" represent the score that somethin is present in the box that others value represent.

I would like the "a" to be calculated with for example binary crossentrophy and others with MSE

In labels the a is either 1 ( the others values are non zero ) , or 0 ( all others values are also zero )

So i would like the a to be between 0 - 1 in output.

I have tried to create my own loss function :

```
def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true[0], y_pred[0]), axis=-1) + K.mean(K.square(y_pred[1:] - y_true[1:]), axis=-1)
```

However it throw quite robust error, the part below is part that provides most informations ( i think )

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [4] vs. [5]
         [[Node: loss/predictions_loss/mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](loss/predictions_loss/Mean_2, _arg_predictions_sample_weights_0_2/_1191)]]
         [[Node: loss/mul/_1305 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_12439_loss/mul", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

What could cause this? The shape 4 v 5 is weird while i the output and input has same shape.

Is there a way how to fix it or workaround?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is your output shape `(samples, 5)` or `(samples, boxes 5)`?

Comment: (samples,boxes,5) , atleast i think it is, im still not orienting well in keras, shape prints (?,15,4)

Comment: What is the last shape in `model.summary()`?

Comment: its (none,15,4)

Comment: ... ok ... then you've got only 4 letters, not five.... do you have more than one output in the model?

Comment: sorry, typo, its (none,15,5) , i have only one output

Comment: @DanielMöller i have found about tf.gather and changed my function to
K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(tf.gather(y_true,0), tf.gather(y_pred,0)), axis=-1)+ K.mean(K.square(tf.gather(y_pred,[1,2,3,4]) - tf.gather(y_true,[1,2,3,4])), axis=-1)  However error remains the same , now its [4] vs [2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your output shape is `(samples, boxes, 5)`.

**Solution**

```
def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    cross = K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true[:,:,:1], y_pred[:,:,:1]), axis=-1) 
    mse = K.mean(K.square(y_pred[:,:,1:] - y_true[:,:,1:]), axis=-1)

    return cross + mse
```

If you still get an incompatibility due to `cross` having a different shape from `mse`, you should probably take a further `K.mean()` until both of them keep shapes either like `(samples, boxes)` or just `(samples,)`.

If you're not going to use any kind of sample weighting, you can just remove the `axis=-1` from the means.

**Wrong dimension**

Don't forget that the first dimension of a tensor is the samples, so you need to take `a` from the last dimension (since the second is "boxes"):

- `y_true[:,:,:1]` has shape `(samples, boxes, 1)`
- `y_true[:,:,1:]` has shape `(samples, boxes, 4)`

I'm using `:1` to keep the last dimension, if you use only `0`, the shape will be `(samples, boxes)`.

Comment: I have one question, using this the first output is stll not normalized between 0 and 1, why is that happening? Shouldnt the loss function do just this?

Comment: There's not "automatic" normalization anywhere in keras. If you want normalized values you need to explicitly call for activation, normalization and custom layers.